# HTML5 History Mode error (Cannot Get /page)

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I implemented Vue-Router into my website in order to help with SEO, but now I'm getting an error "Cannot GET /" for each Vue page in my site.

The odd thing is that this ONLY happens when i refresh a page other than the home page. I have no problem navigating to these site pages using the nav bar, but the second i try to refresh any of them, i get the error.

The app works just fine locally and the pages refresh just fine, but deployed on Heroku, i get this error. Keep in mind that i've switched from hash mode to HTML5 history mode for all my routes. Lastly, my site has these issues, but still loads the home page on a desktop browser.. it won't load at all on mobile devices.

Here's the link to the site: https://autosnapwebsite.herokuapp.com/

Feel free to look at my files: https://github.com/ddg5565/AutosnapWebsite

I have tried every solution I can find online so i'm in real need of some help to diagnose this.

Comment: This is due to your web servers config. Are you using Apache2 or Nginx.

Comment: I'm not sure. I do know that I am using Express and Node.js which I believe is the server I'm running.

Comment: I've looked into this page: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations under the Express using Node.js section. I've tried implementing this solution and have no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to make some adjustments to my server.js file. For anyone having this issue, here's the final version that worked:

```
 // server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = express();
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

app.use(history({
  // verbose: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8080));


// app.listen(port);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`ENV: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  console.log(`Derp is running at localhost: ${app.get('port')}`);
});

// console.log('server started '+ port);
```